# How to explain discrepancies between emmeans output and means?

Tags: r, model, regression, mean, emmeans

I'm using a quasibinomial model in R with a dependent variable and several independent variables (both numeric and dummy variables). I've used `Anova(mymodel)` to test which independent variable affect my dependent variable. One of these variables is a dummy variable (let's call it `dummy1`), so I computed post-hoc contrasts with `emmeans` : `emmeans(my model, specs = pairwise ~ dummy1, nuisance="otherdummyvariable")$contrasts`, which output is:

```
contrast                estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 1 - 2                  0.12587 0.407 Inf   0.309  0.9980
 1 - 3                 -0.14955 0.399 Inf  -0.375  0.9958
 1 - 4                 -0.38213 0.396 Inf  -0.964  0.8711
 1 - 5                 -0.39202 0.396 Inf  -0.989  0.8604
 2 - 3                 -0.27542 0.153 Inf  -1.798  0.3748
 2 - 4                 -0.50799 0.152 Inf  -3.337  0.0075
 2 - 5                 -0.51789 0.177 Inf  -2.925  0.0285
 3 - 4                 -0.23258 0.146 Inf  -1.594  0.5014
 3 - 5                 -0.24247 0.162 Inf  -1.501  0.5621
 4 - 5                 -0.00989 0.152 Inf  -0.065  1.0000
```

I also plotted the mean and 95%IC of each category of *dummy1* :
[here's the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT2gt.png)

**The thing is, as you can see, that the mean of 1 is lower than the mean of 2 but emmeans contrast 1 - 2 gives a positive estimate, same problem with the contrast 2 - 5, etc.**

**Is this usual? Am I missing something?** (I am new to both emmeans and quasibinomial regressions).

I would expect a positive estimate in the case of a positive difference of means and a negative estimates in the case of a negative difference of means.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: This is really a statistical question, not a computing one, and it'd be better to post it on CrossValidated. But when you have several predictors involved, there are a number of technical reasons that EMMs of one factor will differ from the ordinary marginal means of the data. Take a look at  the [Basics of EMMs vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html) which explains how EMMs are obtained from the model (not the data, directly).